# Calculating this combination: $C_{n}^{l}\cdot C_{l}^{l}+C_{n}^{l+1}\cdot C_{l+1}^{l}+\ldots+C_{n}^{n}\cdot C_{n}^{l}=?$

Tags: combinatorics

Calculating this combination:
$$C_{n}^{l}\cdot C_{l}^{l}+C_{n}^{l+1}\cdot C_{l+1}^{l}+\ldots+C_{n}^{n}\cdot C_{n}^{l}=?$$

Comment: $C_n^l={n\choose l}$ or $C_n^l={l\choose n}$?

Comment: @Peter: It has to be the former, non-standard though that is; if it were the latter, every term would be $0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I would think too. That aside, I usually see $C_{n,k}={n\choose k}$, but I had never seen this one.

Comment: @Peter: For $\binom{n}k$ I’ve seen $C(n,k),^nC_k,_nC_k,C_k^n$, and probably one or two more, but this is only the second time that I’ve seen the indices in what I consider the wrong order.

Comment: See also: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380555/prove-that-for-n-m-geq0-that-sum-limits-k-mnk-choosemn-choose
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333148/prove-by-induction-sum-limits-k-m-nn-choose-kk-choose-m-n-choose-m
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640706/combinatorial-argument-for-sum-limits-k-in-binomnk-binomki-bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's necessary to make a more detailed explanation, just as following:

$$\begin{align*}
C_{n}^{l}C_{l}^{l}+C_{n}^{l+1}C_{l+1}^{l}+\dots+C_{n}^{n}C_{n}^{l}
=\sum_{k=l}^{n}C_{n}^{k}C_{k}^{l}
=\sum_{k=l}^{n}C_{n}^{l}C_{n-l}^{k-l}
=2^{n-l}C_{n}^{l}
\end{align*}$$

The second step follows from that for arbitrary $k$,

$$\begin{align*}
C_{n}^{k}C_{k}^{l}&=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{k!}{l!(k-l)!}\\
&=\frac{n!}{l!(n-k)!(k-l)!}\\
&=\frac{n!}{l!(n-l)!}\frac{(n-l)!}{(n-k)!(k-l)!}\\
&=C_{n}^{l}C_{n-l}^{k-l}\\
\end{align*}$$

The last step follows from that

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=l}^{n}C_{n}^{l}C_{n-l}^{k-l}&=C_{n}^{l}\sum_{k=l}^{n}C_{n-l}^{k-l}
=C_{n}^{l}\sum_{i=0}^{n-l}C_{n-l}^{i}\\
&=C_{n}^{l}2^{n-l}=2^{n-l}C_{n}^{l}\\
\end{align*}$$

that's all, thanks for reading.

Comment: Why did you submit a nearly-identical answer 6 minutes after your first one?

Comment: @Rick Decker: After I typed out the first one, I found that I was so careless that I haven't make use of $$ pairs to enclose mathematics to be displayed, so I submit a nearly-identical answer to replaced it. Thanks for your reminding and guiding.

Comment: @AlfredChern note that by pressing the edit button at the bottom left hand corner you can change your answer without having to post a new one.

Comment: @E.O.: Thanks for reminding and guiding. I know how to deal with it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve it purely computationally:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=\ell}^n\binom{n}k\binom{k}\ell&=\sum_{k=\ell}^n\frac{n!k!}{k!(n-k)!\ell!(k-\ell)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=\ell}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-\ell)!\ell!}\\
&=\binom{n}\ell\sum_{k=\ell}^n\frac{(n-\ell)!}{(n-k)!(k-\ell)}!\\
&=\binom{n}\ell\sum_{k=0}^{n-\ell}\binom{n-\ell}k\\
&=\binom{n}\ell2^{n-\ell}\;.
\end{align*}$$

You can also resolve it combinatorially. Imagine that you have $n$ white balls. You’re going to paint $\ell$ of them red, and then you’re going to choose some (or perhaps none) of the remaining white balls and paint them blue. You can do this by first choosing $k$ balls, for some $k\ge\ell$, that are going to be painted either blue or red, and then choosing $\ell$ of these $k$ balls to be painted red; the other $k-\ell$ of the balls will be painted blue. For a particular value of $k$ the number of ways to do this is $\binom{n}k\binom{k}\ell$, so

$$\sum_{k=\ell}^n\binom{n}k\binom{k}\ell$$

is the total number of ways to carry out the task.

On the other hand, you could simply choose $\ell$ of the $n$ balls and paint them red, and then go through the other $n-\ell$ balls one at a time, either painting the ball blue or leaving it white. There are $\binom{n}\ell2^{n-\ell}$ ways to do this. Thus,

$$\sum_{k=\ell}^n\binom{n}k\binom{k}\ell=\binom{n}\ell2^{n-\ell}\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$C_{n}^{l}.C_{l}^{l}+C_{n}^{l+1}.C_{l+1}^{l}+\ldots+C_{n}^{n}.C_{n}^{l}
=\sum_{k=l}^{n}C_{n}^{k}.C_{k}^{l}
=\sum_{k=l}^{n}C_{n}^{l}.C_{n-l}^{k-l}
=2^{n-l}C_{n}^{l}
$$

Comment: How did you make the last step?

Comment: @Norbert That is probably listed in Wikipedia in the zillion binomial identities list. =)

Comment: @Norbert See the [Identities with combinatorial proofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients) section

Answer (score 0):

I think it's necessary to make a more detailed explanation, just as following:
$$
C_{n}^{l}C_{l}^{l}+C_{n}^{l+1}C_{l+1}^{l}+\dots+C_{n}^{n}C_{n}^{l}
=\sum_{k=l}^{n}C_{n}^{k}C_{k}^{l}
=\sum_{k=l}^{n}C_{n}^{l}C_{n-l}^{k-l}
=2^{n-l}C_{n}^{l}
$$
The second step follows from that for arbitrary $k$,
$$
\begin{align} 
C_{n}^{k}C_{k}^{l}
&=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{k!}{l!(k-l)!}\\
&=\frac{n!}{l!.(n-k)!(k-l)!}\\
&=\frac{n!}{l!.(n-l)!}\frac{(n-l)!}{(n-k)!(k-l)!}\\
&=C_{n}^{l}.C_{n-l}^{k-l}
\end{align}
$$
The last step follows from that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=l}^{n}C_{n}^{l}C_{n-l}^{k-l}
&=C_{n}^{l}\sum_{k=l}^{n}C_{n-l}^{k-l}\text{ (as $k$ replaced by $i+l$)}\\
&=C_{n}^{l}\sum_{i=0}^{n-l}C_{n-l}^{i}\\
&=C_{n}^{l}2^{n-l}
\end{align}
$$
that's all, thanks for reading.

Comment: Your markup was almost correct. Make use of $$ pairs to enclose mathematics to be displayed. Look at the source of my edits to see how it's done.

Comment: @Rick Decker: Thank you very much! I had look at the source of your edits, it's perfect and I have learned from it. I am not very familiar with the rules and thanks for guide.