# Prove combinatorics identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Prove that for $n,m\geq0$, that

> $\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}{{k}\choose{m}}{{n}\choose{k}}=2^{n-m}{{n}\choose{m}}$.

---

I wrote $2^{n-m}$ as $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-m}{{n-m}\choose{k}}$ using the binomial theorem. Then I drew a Venn-diagram with a set $A$ which has $k$ elements, and a set $B$ which is a subset of $A$ with $m$ elements. from which I think you can interpret the left side of the equality in the question as the number of ways in which you can first choose $k$ elements from the sample space (with n elements) and then choose $m$ elements from $A$. However, I am not entirely sure how to interpret the right side of the inequality then. Could anyone please comment on my approach and tell me what I should do next if it's correct and otherwise tell me how else it should be done?

Furthermore, could anyone please tell me how I should interpret the summation in terms of combinatorics? Because I do not really see what the summation does in terms of sets/how I should visualize this in a diagram or how I should just see this in general. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure about "which is equal to..." Shouldn't that be "which is equal to $\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}{{n-m}\choose{k-m}}$?"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Why would that be so? Doesn't the way I transform the summation ensure we sum over the same number of elements still (namely in total over $n-m$ elements)?

Comment: You get the same number of elements but they are not the same elements. Your original sum, for instance, has a term $\binom{n-m}{0}$ which does not occur in your second sum.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right, that is a sloppy mistake. I'll correct my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not apply the binomial theorem to the power of $2$.

You have a set of $n$ white balls. You want to paint $m$ of them blue and possibly some of the remaining $n-m$ balls red. You can choose the $m$ blue balls in $\binom{n}m$ ways, and there are then $2^{n-m}$ subsets of the remaining $n-m$ balls that you could choose to color red, so there are $2^{n-m}\binom{n}m$ ways to carry out the task.

Alternatively, you could choose $k\ge m$ balls to be colored something other than white and then choose $m$ of these to be painted blue, leaving the other $m-k$ to be painted red; this can be done in $\binom{n}k\binom{k}m$ ways. The possible values of $k$ are the integers from $m$ through $n$, so the lefthand side of the equation counts all possibilities, and the two sides must be equal.

If $S$ is the entire set of balls, $B$ is the set of blue balls, and $R$ is the set of red balls, then the righthand side corresponds to picking $B$ and then picking $R$ from $S\setminus B$. The lefthand side corresponds to picking $R\cup B$ of some cardinality between $m$ and $n$ inclusive, and then choosing $B$ from $R\cup B$.

Comment: +1 Very nice.  I was about to write up something similar in terms of picking subsets, but here the painting visual makes things much clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The only thing which I do not really understand yet is why there are then $2^{n-m}$ subsets left to color red after choosing the m blue balls. Could you please elaborate on why this is true?

Comment: @cruise:  If you have a set with $n-m$ elements in it, there are $2^{n-m}$ total subsets of that set.  (List the elements in order.  Each subset is determined by a sequence of $n-m$ 0's or 1's.  If the $i$-th position has a 1, that means the subset contains the $i$-th element in the list.  For example, if $n-m=5$, then after listing the five elements in any order you like, the sequence 10110 would correspond to the subset which has the first, third, and fourth element from the list in it.)

Comment: How do you come up with such constructions?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelJoyce :)

Comment: Could anyone please tell me what the meaning of the summation is, or how I should interpret it in terms of combinatorics as well?

Comment: @cruise: That's what the paragraph beginning with *Alternatively* is about: it's a combinatorial explanation of the summation.

Comment: @Peter: Experience, and maybe a bit of a knack for it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Having reread your answer today, there is one thing that I have a question about. You wrote: 'and the two sides must be equal'. I get that this is true by intuition, but would it be possible to show that this is true by defining a bijective function that maps the set on the lefthand side of the equality to the one on the righthand side(to then use the one-to-one rule that thus their cardinality is equal)? Because this is what my professor used in solving similar problems in the lecture, I remember.

Answer (score 3):

Show $C_k^m C_n^k=C_n^m C_{n-m}^{k-m}$. (forgive my different notation.)

Comment: I can edit it to get the different format, if you would not mind.

Answer (score 3):

Brute-force (not elegant):
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m}^{n}{{k}\choose{m}}{{n}\choose{k}}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}{{k+m}\choose{m}}{{n}\choose{k+m}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\frac{(k+m)!}{m!k!}\frac{n!}{(n-m-k)!(m+k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}\frac{(n-m)!}{k!(n-m-k)!}\\
&= \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\frac{(n-m)!}{k!(n-m-k)!}\\
&= {{n}\choose{m}}2^{n-m}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I prefer the more intuitive approach in this case but it's nice to see how the problem can be solved algebraically.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write $2^n \binom{n}{m}$ as the number of ways of picking two subsets, $S_1,S_2 \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$ independently with the condition that $|S_2|=m$.

Let $T_1=S_1\cup S_2, T_2=S_2\cap S_1$.

Then we can see that $\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m}2^m$ counts the number of ways of picking a $T_1\subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ of size $k$, then $S_2$ of size $m$ inside $T_1$, then a random subset $S_2$ of $T_1$ or size $m$, and then a random subset of $T_2$ of $S_2$. Then $S_1$ is uniquely determined as $(T_1\setminus S_2)\cup T_2$.

Basically, $k=|S_1\cup S_2|$.