# Prove by double-counting: $\sum_{k=d} ^n {n \choose k} {k \choose d} = 2^ {(n-d)} {n \choose d} $?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I'm thinking the left hand side is picking k people from n people and then picking d people from k people.
For the right hand side, we have picking d people from n people first and this is where I'm stuck.
I think I must explain $2^ {(n-d)}$ to be equal as picking k people from n people

Comment: Did you check some other posts on this site about this sum? For example, [Combinatorial argument for $\sum\limits_{k=i}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{i} = \binom{n}{i}2^{n-i}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1640706). (I search for related posts [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3Dd%7D%20%5En%20%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%20k%7D%20%7Bk%20%5Cchoose%20d%7D%24&p=1). Some useful tips on searching can be found here: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265))

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Lets say that you have fence(wood sticks in a row) of length $n,$ you want to paint exactly $d$ of them blue. For painting them you have to put a white base first. The left hand side is **first** picking the $k$ ones you will paint white and from those the $d$ you are painting blue. The RHS is picking the blue **first** and then just choosing some $k$(you do not need to know exactly how many(can be any number $k$ between none and the remainder $n-d$)) for paint the remainder white.